# Biztalk Server 2006 64bit problem

Tags: 64-bit

I am trying to install a 64-bit biztalk server 2006. However when I start my installation it asks if I want to get my .cab file from the internet or install it manually etc. Because of internet security issues here at our work we can't get it from the internet directly. So I downloaded it manually: BtsRedistW2k3EN64.cab, to be exact.

However when I try to install this it complains about:

> This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor.

I opened the cab file and found out that the file: SQLServer2005_ADOMD.msi was apparently the problem. So I thought I'd install the 64bit version of this msi then: SQLServer2005_ADOMD_x64.msi, however I get the same error. So atm I'm pretty stuck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have see this error message with corrupted installers.  I would try re-downloading the .msi file and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid question but are you sure that you are using a 64 bit edition of Windows?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Garrett - It is the answer in the form of a question!

Comment: IMO should be a comment until confirmed otherwise.